# Performance of array analysis using Arrays.sort

Tags: java, performance, big-o, code-analysis

I have a code that uses `Arrays.sort(char[])` in the following manner:

```
    void arrayAnalysis(String[] array){
      for(int a=0; a<array.length;a++){
        char[] letters = array[a].toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(letters);
        ...
        for(int b=a+1; b<array.length;b++){
          char[] letters2 = array[b].toCharArray();
          Arrays.sort(letters2);

          if(Arrays.equals(letters, letters2)
            print("equal");
        }
      }
    }
```

In this case, n is equal to the array size. Due to the nested for loops, performance is automatically O(n^2). However, I think Arrays.sort (with O(nlog(n))) also affects the performance and makes it worse than O(n^2). Is this thinking correct?

Would the final performance be O(n*nlog(n)*(n*nlog(n))? Or am I way off?

Thanks.

Edit: I should add that while n is related to the array size, Arrays.sort is working with the number of letters in the array element. That is part of my confusion if this should be added to the performance analysis.

Edit2: It would be cool if the down-voter left a comment as to why it was deemed as a bad question.

Comment: How long are your strings? That's the `n` in your Arrays.sort big O, and it's not the same as the `n` in your array size. If you've got a maximum string length, the Arrays.sort bit is bounded by a constant.

Comment: Then your complexity estimate will depend not just on `n` but also the string sizes. Good answer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ChrisNash, I did not think about the bounding size before. About the answer below, my confusion is whether or not the initial sort is ignored.

Comment: Understood, you're seeing an outer sort `O(m log m)` and an inner sort `O(m log m)`. But they're sequential operations, so they *add*, not *multiply* ( And remember `O(something) + O(something smaller)` is still `O(something)` ). The important bit is how many sorts there are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `n` is the length of the array, and `m` is the length of each `array[i]`, then you will, on each of `n^2` iterations, perform an `O(m log m)` sort, so overall it's `O(n^2 (m log m))` (Or `O(n^3 log n)` if `n == m`. [EDIT: now that I think more about this, your guess is right, and this is the wrong complexity. But what I say below is still correct!]]

This is not really necessary, though. You could just make a sorted copy of the array, and do your nested for-loop using that one. Look at what happens when `a` is 0: first you sort `array[0]`, then in the inner for loop you sort `array[1]` through `array[n]`.

Then when `a` is 1, you first sort `array[1]`, then in the inner for loop `array[2]` through `array[n]`. *But you already sorted all that*, and it's not as if it will have changed in the interim.

Comment: I think you overlooked the `Arrays.sort(char[])` call within the outer loop. However, what you said makes perfect sense. It is a way to improve the performance.

Comment: Sort the arrays once. That's `O(n (m log m))`. Comparing the arrays is then a nested loop, and that's `O(n^2 m)`, since worst-case, you have to compare `m` characters in each.

Comment: It's a cute question, because the relative sizes of `n` and `m` actually makes a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You run *n* outer loops, each of which runs *n* inner loops, each of which calls an O(*n* log *n*) algorithm, so the final result — absent any interaction between the levels — is O(*n*<sup>3</sup> log *n*).

Comment: There is a O(n log n) algorithm call within the outer loop as well.